# Return binary string as plain text in browser window (and not as a downloadable file)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to return the following protobuf serialised binary data to the browser (Chrome) and **not** as a downloadable file.  I don't understand the mechanism that is prompting a download.  It is not the mime type as I am using `text/plain` elsewhere.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GenerateProtoFeed()
{
    var feed = _gtfsrService.GenerateFeed();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        feed.WriteTo(stream);

        stream.Position = 0;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return Content(reader.ReadToEnd(), "text/plain");
        }
    }
}
```

What I really want is this (example) to be returned in the browser window:

```
2.0?????/?
-Mcycmmp9-o4C0qeoGdz*?
????/*0
rE6s0CN800STv61PAKtfHAL6wS0jjmZkSZwq1PAKtf8A08Z?
?
?#StationAlert Elevators at Commercial-Broadway and Brentwood Stations are temporarily out of service today. ^sdken
```

Comment: If it is binary data, Encoding.ASCII will convert byte values above 127 to a `?` - which may or may not be important in this particular case

Comment: A guess: The file is not really a text file and the heuristics in the browser detects undisplayable characters and thus falls back to a download. **Is** the file actually text? I mean, does it contain those specific characters you see there?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it is actually binary data.  The ASCII encoding above is indeed incorrect.  Yes, it seems the browser is sniffing the contents.

Answer (score 1):

The browser handles responses from a server differently depending on how the user has configured it, and on the [mime type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) of the response.

It looks like your browser's default behaviour for `text/plain` is to prompt a save action. If you set the mime type of your response to `text/html`, the browser should simply display it.

Note that this is of course technically incorrect in this case.

Comment: The strange thing is that I am using text/plain elsewhere without this issue.  In fact, I can replace the `reader.ReadToEnd()` with "xyz" and it proceeds to print in the browser.